# Duplicates CI Jobs and If Condition doesn't work

Tags: gitlab-ci

When I run following Gitlab CI, it invokes duplicate for both jobs(i.e 4 pipelines). What I need here is to invoke only one job if the condition qualifies

```
default:
  image: 'napp/docker-aws-cli'

variables:
  AWS_BUCKET: ******-docker
  PM_S3_FOLDER: ********_manager
  SNAP_S3_FOLDER: ********_GDAL3_SNAP

********_manager:
  inherit:
    default: [image]
    variables: [PM_S3_FOLDER]
  script:
    - zip -jrm Dockerfile.zip docker_containers/********_manager/redis/Dockerfile docker_containers/********_manager/redis/buildspec.yaml
    - aws s3 cp Dockerfile.zip s3://******-docker/$PM_S3_FOLDER/
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      changes:  # Include the job and set to when:manual if any of the follow paths match a modified file.
        - ********/docker_containers/********_manager/redis/Dockerfile 
        - ********/docker_containers/********_manager/redis/buildspec.yaml
      allow_failure: true
      when: never
    - when: on_success

snap:
  inherit:
    default: [image]
    variables: [SNAP_S3_FOLDER]
  script:
    - zip -jrm Dockerfile.zip docker_containers/********_GDAL3_SNAP/Dockerfile docker_containers/********_GDAL3_SNAP/buildspec.yaml
    - aws s3 cp Dockerfile.zip s3://signaleyes-docker/$SNAP_S3_FOLDER/
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      changes:  # Include the job and set to when:manual if any of the follow paths match a modified file.
        - ********/docker_containers/********_GDAL3_SNAP/Dockerfile
        - ********/docker_containers/********_GDAL3_SNAP/buildspec.yaml
      allow_failure: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with the rules of the inherit job

```
- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
  changes:  # Include the job and set to when:manual if any of the follow paths match a modified file.
    - ********/docker_containers/********_manager/redis/Dockerfile 
    - ********/docker_containers/********_manager/redis/buildspec.yaml
  allow_failure: true
  when: never
- when: on_success
```

Quoting from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#rules-examples

*If you use a **when clause** as the **final rule** (not including when: never), two simultaneous pipelines may start. **Both** push pipelines and merge request pipelines can be triggered by the **same event** (a push to the source branch for an open merge request).*

In order to avoid this rewrite the rules to run the job only in very specific cases, and avoid a final when rule. In your case remove

```
- when: on_success
```

Or use [workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#workflow) to specify which types of pipelines can run